# How can I store numbers in arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I built a program that check if there are two common numbers in two different arrays, and then log those numbers. I was able to do that using a simple for loop that goes trough each element of the first array and check if there is an equal element in the second array. Each of the same element in the arrays are stored in a third array called "commonNumbers" which I logged at the end of the program.

```
const firstNumbers = [12, 45, 6, 78] 
const secondNumbers = [6, 7, 12, 45] 
let commonNumbers = []

for (let i = 0; i < firstNumbers.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < secondNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (firstNumbers[i] === secondNumbers[j]) {
            commonNumbers += secondNumbers[j]
        }
    } }

console.log(commonNumbers)
```

The result for this example is the seguent:

```
12456
[Finished in 0.2s]
```

My question is about the result. I can see that the program actually worked and logged the same element in the arrays (12, 45, 6), but I can't figure out why "commonNumbers" stored the result in such a way that there are no spaces between the numbers.

I would like to clearly see each number.

For example if I call the first element of "commonNumbers" (of index 0):
`commonNumbers[0]` the result I will get is not going to be "12" as expected, but "1".
Same thing happen if I say: `commonNumbers[2]` the result is going to be "4", not "6".

Apparently "commonNumbers" array stored the element in a different way I was expecting. How can I solve this, using this "storing" method?

Comment: `commonNumbers += secondNumbers[j]` <-- += on an array does not actually act like adding an element. To add an element to an array, use `.push`: `commonNumbers.push(secondNumbers[j]);`. To make it clear, `+=` on an array implicitly convert the array to a string.

Comment: You can use a `filter` one liner here so solve that easier `const commonNumbers = firstNumbers.filter(x => secondNumbers.includes(x));`

Comment: Replace ```commonNumbers += secondNumbers[j]``` with ```commonNumbers[commonNumbers.length-1] = secondNumbers[j]``` this will add the common number to the next available slot in the array commonNumbers

Comment: @Virx please don't do that, use `.push` as it's intended :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `+=`, on your array, implicitly convert it to a **string**, as you can see in the example below, where a **Number** is summed to an **Array**.

```js
console.log(typeof([] + 1));
```

Just use the comfortable `.push` ([read more about push here)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) method of arrays in order to add the element:

```
const firstNumbers = [12, 45, 6, 78] 
const secondNumbers = [6, 7, 12, 45] 
let commonNumbers = []

for (let i = 0; i < firstNumbers.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < secondNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (firstNumbers[i] === secondNumbers[j]) {
            commonNumbers.push(secondNumbers[j]);
        }
    } }

console.log(commonNumbers)
```

As a (final) side note, there are several other ways to accomplish your task, the cleverest you can probably go with is `filter`. You may also would take care of eventual duplicates, since if your input array has two identical numbers the commonsNumber result will contain both, which might be unintended.

The "definitive" clever solution that tries to also take care of duplicates and to loop the shorter array would be something like this:

```js
// Inputs with duplicates, and longer array on second case.
const firstNumbers = [12, 45, 6, 78, 12, 12, 6, 45]; 
const secondNumbers = [6, 7, 12, 45, 45, 45, 12, 6, 99, 19, 5912, 9419, 1, 4, 8, 6, 52, 45];

// Performance: look for duplicates starting from the shortest array. Also, make a set to remove duplicate items.
const [shortestArray, longestArray] = firstNumbers.length < secondNumbers.length ? [firstNumbers, secondNumbers] : [secondNumbers, firstNumbers];


// Remove duplicates.
const dedupes = [...new Set(shortestArray)];

// Find commomn items using filter.
const commons = dedupes.filter(i => longestArray.indexOf(i) > -1);
console.log('commons is', commons);
```

Don't get me wrong, the solution is fine, just wanted to add "something" to the boilerplate, to take care of eventual additional scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
const firstNumbers = [12, 45, 6, 78] 
const secondNumbers = [6, 7, 12, 45] 
let commonNumbers = []

for (let i = 0; i < firstNumbers.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < secondNumbers.length; j++) {
        if (firstNumbers[i] === secondNumbers[j]) {
            commonNumbers.push(secondNumbers[j])
        }
    } }
```

The push method appends values to an array.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for `array.prototype.push` ([mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)). E.g.:

```js
const firstNumbers = [12, 45, 6, 78] 
const secondNumbers = [6, 7, 12, 45] 
let commonNumbers = []

for (let i = 0; i < firstNumbers.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < secondNumbers.length; j++)
        if (firstNumbers[i] === secondNumbers[j])
            commonNumbers.push(secondNumbers[j]);
            
console.log(commonNumbers); // as an array
console.log(commonNumbers.join(', '));
```

> **why "commonNumbers" stored the result in such a way that there are no spaces between the numbers.**

The `+` operator will try to cast its operands to compatible types. In this case, that is a string, where empty arrays `[]` are cast to empty strings `''`, and numbers `3` are cast to the corresponding string `'3'`. E.g. `[] + 3` is the string `'3'`.

```js
console.log([], typeof []);
console.log(3, typeof 3);
console.log([] + 3, typeof ([] + 3));
```